# Ant build in Eclipse with Weblogic 9.2 - deployment exception - Unable to connect to 't3://localhost:7001': invalid type code: 31

Tags: eclipse, ant, weblogic

It gives me the following exception message as I am trying to deploy an application.

BUILD FAILED
C:\eclipse\workspace\SLGIADMIN\build.xml:14: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\eclipse\buildcommon.xml:243: weblogic.Deployer$DeployerException: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 't3://localhost:7001': invalid type code: 31. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.

I am using ant build in Eclipse and deploying to Weblogic 9.2.

I have been trying to find solution online. I have tried enable the tunneling in the Weblogic console. Doesn't work.
I have seen people mention we can use JDK 1.5 which will turn on tunneling on deploying. I have verified mine version is 1.5 too. I have ensured that too but did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid type code 31 is always because you're connecting with a different version of Java than what the server is running. Weblogic 9.2 only supports Java 1.5. Make sure that's what your ant task is using. You can also connect with later versions of Java if you set the following property in your client:

```
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
```

Comment: I think I am using 1.5 for both my project's compiler and the ant build. My ant build points to JDK folder that comes with the Weblogic installation, C:\bea92\jdk150_10